# How to model "Sparial Variability" or "Choice of Location"

Tags: modeling, econometrics, spatial

Lets say I have survey data on 10000 delivery-man. I have number of delivery they made in 49 neighborhoods (that is 49 columns plus 01 as "other neighborhoods") and one column as their earning per hour (EPH). I am trying to explain that a person's EPH depends on his choice of negihborhoods to work in.

For initial exploration, I divided the 10000 into 10 groups (based on EPH, low to high) and plotted the fraction of delivery they made in different neighborhoods. It is clear from the graph that high earning group pick the rich neighborhoods more. (I arbitratly picked a neighbood that I know rich people live in vs a neighborhood I know to be poor. Also, I picked "fraction of delivery made in neighborhood X" instead of "total delivery" because different delivery person has differnt experience).

My question is how do I statistically model the variation in EPH due to choice of neighborhoods? What kind of regression model should I be studying? How will the fact that neighborhoods are usually correlated will affect my modelling?

Additionally,

1) I have data from the delivery company which tells me true EPH per neighborhood, aggregated over ALL delivery for ALL delivery person. That is 125 rows for 125 neighborhoods and 2 columns with EPH and Total Delivery. How do I incorporate this information in my modelling?

2) I have the Well-Known Text representation of the neighborhoods.